# Как не показывать кнопку "Cancel" у UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

Таким образом я пытаюсь сделать, чтобы кнопка "Cancel" не показывалась:

```
- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
```

При нажатии на текстовое поле UISearchBar кнопка на момент появляется и исчезает.

Я попробовал сделать тоже самое в методе, который вызывается чуть раньше:

```
- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
    searchController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}
```

Безрезультатно, в метод `didPresentSearchController` свойство `showsCancelButton` приходит `YES`. Из-за этого кнопка появляется на момент и исчезает, после установления свойства в `NO`. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

знающие люди советуют сабклассить UISearchBar и там убирать кнопку в `layoutSubviews` (взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496310/hide-uisearchbar-cancel-button))

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self setShowsCancelButton:NO animated:NO];
}
```

если, допустим у вас есть свой сабкласс `MySearchController` и есть свой сабкласс для бара `MySearchBar`, примерно вот так это будет выглядеть (сам не пробовал)

```
@interface MySearchController ()

@property (nonatomic) MySearchBar *myBar;

@end

@implementation MySearchController

- (UISearchBar*)searchBar
{
    if(!_myBar) {
        _myBar = [MySearchBar new];
    }
    return _myBar;
}

@end
```

Comment: А как после этого переопределить searchBar у searchController?

Comment: эпл говорит, надо и UISearchController наследовать и заменять бар на свой > To use a custom subclass of UISearchBar, subclass UISearchController and implement this property to return your custom search bar.

Comment: Не получается у меня переопределитить property. Не мог бы ты подсказать, как точно это сделать?

Comment: добавил в ответ (сам это запускать не пробовал)

Comment: К сожалению не работает. Геттер ни разу не вызывается